# Javascript for altering padding in css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've encountered a problem while coding my website row by row. For specifying products I have made small slideshows for every one of them, but I have a hard time centering the images vertically due to some pictures are standing and some are laying down. I use "text-align: center" for horisontall centering, but since the pictures heights varies I've been trying to use js.

Here's how far I've come trying to code a script that calculates the top-padding depending on how high the image is:

```
    function padding(nr) {
var heightPX = document.getElementsByClassName("IMG"+nr).clientHeight;
document.getElementById("frame"+nr).style.paddingTop = ((290-s)/2); 
}
```

290 is the maximum height, so 290-s is what's left over, and then divided by 2 for the same space over and under.. You get the idea, this isn't working though.
Help pls

Comment: You can probably just do this with CSS. Are you interested in a CSS solution? If so post your markup.

Comment: And seems like this solution would depend on knowing the parent element's height, too. (`parent element's height` - `image height`) / 2 = padding value.

Comment: Okey if it's possible that would be great!

Comment: post your html markup

Comment: This is a good use case for flex.

Comment: css solution. nothing fancy. https://designpieces.com/2012/12/vertical-centering-image-in-a-div/

Comment: I would advise you to use flexbox display mode to avoid vertical centering headaches.

Comment: @CarlJonsson ok answered with an example.

Comment: Okey, applying position: absolute to the main image, and also adding top: 50% and margin-top: -Xpx is working, but the problem about different heights for every image and therefore diferent Xs remains...

Answer (score 1):

You can center an element vertically using a combination of `display: flex; align-items: center;` on the parent element. There are other techniques covered here https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html

```css
img {
  max-height: 50vh;
}
div {
  height: 100vh;
  background: #333;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png">
</div>
```